# How do I show a teaser of external content in Drupal 7

Tags: nodes

I want to be able to create a node that shows a teaser from an external page. So the user would create a new node, add a link to the page and then the body would show a teaser of the content from the external website. When the user clicks on the link it should open a separate page or tab and redirect the user to the original content. Similar to what Linkedin and Facebook do when you attach a link for a status update. I have tried the Statuses module and the microblogger modules but they are really buggy. Any suggestions?

Facebook has this cool functionality: when you post something that seems to be a link, it will automaticly parse the linked site and show you

The content of the title-tag

A Teaser of the Text (I don't know how it is able to identify the content area, but it seems to be very reliable)

An Image taken from the site (it present you every img-tag and you can choose witch you want to show)

For example when I enter this site:
http://www.air-watch.com/company/news-room/press-releases/2012/03/flight-options-first-in-industry-to-receive-ipad-class-1-electronic-flight

The title will look like this:

```
Case Study: Flight Options First in Industry to Receive iPad® Class 1 Electronic Flight Bag Authorization | drupal.org
```

And this text will be fetched as teaser:

```
Basic EFB features provide the ability to conduct flight planning calculations and access digital documentation displays such as navigational charts, operation manuals and applications and aircraft checklists.
```

The image piece is a nice to have but not mandatory. There is a module that will allow me to pull that separately.

Comment: I think you should handle it your self using curl extension. try to fetch and parse contents from url on hook_node_presave and save it as teaser.